# Piping stdout of one subprocess to stdin of another subprocess not yielding expected results

Tags: python, linux, pipe, subprocess

I'm trying to process a log file to extract some info from the end of the file. The log files are huge and the info I'm looking for are at the end of the file.
I'm using python subprocess methods to achieve this as follows:

```
p1.subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-n', '100', logFile], stdout=PIPE)
p2.subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'Output[ 1 ].*Perf'], stdin=p1.stdout,
                    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
procOut,procErr = p2.communicate()
print procOut # Nothing gets printed
```

Wondering if I'm doing something terribly wrong here. When I execute these two piped commands in shell, I get the output I'm looking for. However not when I'm trying to do it in Python.

Comment: What *do* you get when you run that script in Python?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Please include sample input, and both expected and actual output.

Comment: Can you post the content of `logFile`, so we can test it using Python and Shell?

Comment: Since the logfile is probably too large to post, instead you could upload a copy of it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) then [edit] your question and add a link to that to it.

Comment: You guys helped a lot by asking the right question. The log file has a line 'Output[ 1 ]: 200, timestamp(ps): 1312312311213 ps, Perf: 1232312' The issue was in my grep statement 'Output[ 1 ].*Perf'. I was supposed to grep 'Output\\[ 1 \\].*Perf' instead. That fixed my issue. Thanks a lot for your help.